# mediawiki content version management

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

We have mediawiki as our wiki site.
Is it possible to manage many pages as a release with version, e.g. 1.1.
And after we update some pages to new, I also can simple select 1.1 to read 1.1 content only?

Page level history looks work for one page with timestamp, but it is not easy to manage many pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have this need too.

I did not try https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Memento yet, but it seems that it could do the job.